# Remove "empty" paragraphs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

My writers have a bad habit of creating empty paragraphs. (I.e., paragraphs that have nothing inside them, like:

```
<p></p>
```

Is there a jQuery function that removes "empty" paragraphs. Here's what I've tried:

```
$('p').remove(":contains(' ')"); // nope! bad logic, all p's have empty spaces 

$("p:empty").remove() // nope, doesn't work, doesn't remove any p's
```

Anything else I should try?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`$("p:empty").remove()` works for me (demo at http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/XwABG/1/).  Make sure your elements are actually empty and don't contain any white space.

You can always use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
// Trimming white space
$('p').filter(function () { return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == "" }).remove();

// Without trimming white space
$('p').filter(function () { return this.innerHTML == "" }).remove();
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/XwABG/**

Comment: could also user `this.innerHTML` or `$(this).text()`

Comment: @Neal: switched to `this.innerHTML` for performance.  My knee-jerk reaction is usually to go for text, but that requires browser checks or recursion.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work with any number of spaces (sorry I'm not sure I understood whether there was spaces in the paragraphs or not):

```
$("p").each(function(){
  if ($.trim($(this).text()) == ""){
    $this.remove();
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend Andy's answer to non-breakable spaces 
(and use string's trim() method instead of jquery's), you may use:

```
$('p').filter(function () { 
    return this.innerHTML
        .replace("&nbsp;"," ")
        .trim() 
        == "" 
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is plain old JavaScript and it's very fast:

```
[].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"), function(elem){return elem.childElementCount==0 && elem.textContent.trim()==''})
    .forEach(function(elem){elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem)})
```

This one is even faster:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); 
for (var i = 0, len = paragraphs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var elem = paragraphs[i];
    if (elem.childElementCount == 0 && elem.textContent.trim() == '') {
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        i--;
        len--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .each to iterate over all paragraphs and check for innerHTML empty and remove those

Answer (score 0):

If the empty paragraphs are

then fireeyedboy's p:empty selector is the way to go :-

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
        $this.remove();
});
```