# How to remove P tags surrounding img using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've got a webpage that is outputted through CKEditor. I need it to display the image without the `<p></p>` tags but I need it to leave the actual text within the paragraph tags so I can target it for styling.

I've tried to achieve this through the jQuery below that I found on another post here but it isn't working for me..

I have tried:

```
$('img').unwrap();
```

and I've tried:

```
$('p > *').unwrap();
```

Both of these don't work. I can disable the tags altogether from my editors config, but I wont be able to target the text on it's own if it's not wrapped in a tag.

The outputted HTML is:

```
<body>
<div id="container" class="container">
<p><img alt="" src="http://localhost/integrated/uploads/images/roast-dinner-main-xlarge%281%29.jpg" style="height:300px; width:400px" /></p><p>Our roast dinners are buy one get one free!</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('p > *').unwrap();
});
</script>
</body>
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the generated HTML here...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Just added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually done using

```
$('img').unwrap("p");
```

but this will also orphan any other content (like text) from it's `<p>` parent (that contained the image).

So basically you want to move the image out of the `<p>` tags.
There's two places you can move your image: **before** or **after** the `p` tag:

```js
$("p:has(img)").before(function() { // or use .after()
  return $(this).find("img");
});
```

```css
p {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container" class="container">
  <p>
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f0b" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Our roast dinners are buy one get one free!
  </p>
</div>

<p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f0b" alt="">
  Lorem ipsum dolor ay ay
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/0bf" alt="">
</p>

<p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/0bf" alt="">
</p>
```

although notice that the above will **not remove** the empty `<p>` tags we left behind. [See here how to remove empty `p` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823914/remove-empty-paragraphs-with-jquery)

#### Remedy

If you want to **remove the empty paragraphs** - if the image was the only child -
and keep paragraphs that had both image and other content:

```js
$("p:has(img)").each(function() {
    $(this).before( $(this).find("img") );
    if(!$.trim(this.innerHTML).length) $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
p{
  background:red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="container">
  <p>
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f0b" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Our roast dinners are buy one get one free!
  </p>
</div>

<p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f0b" alt="">
  Lorem ipsum dolor ay ay
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/0bf" alt="">
</p>

<p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/0bf" alt="">
</p>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get my paragraph on top of the image, but my CSS for this along with your code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `code`
.container {
                height: 540px !important;
                width: 640px !important;
                border: 1px solid black;
                z-index: -2;
 
}
 
img {
                height: 540px !important;
                width: 640px !important;
                z-index: -1;
                opacity: 0.2;
}
 
p {
                margin-top: 0 !important;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 25px;
                font-style: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                z-index: 5;
}
`code`

Comment: Boom! It works, just had to set the img to relative and p to absolute and it works. Your a legend! Thank you.

Comment: @Coder994 glad you did it!

Answer (score 0):

**This will work for sure**

```js
var par = $(".par");
var tmp = par.find('.img').clone();
var parent = par.parent();
par.remove();
tmp.appendTo(parent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
 <p class="par">
  <img src="https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-src.png" class="img" alt="">
 </p>
</div>
```